# replace a title with name

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string:

```
st = "Dee Fee, MD is a good person. Kas Egre, MD came here"
```

I want to replace `", MD"` with `"Name:"` and put it before name, so the new string should be:

`new = "Name: Dee Fee is a good person. Name: Kas Egre came here"`

I write the following code, it works, but it does not give what I want. The result is this:

```
Name: Dee Fee, MD is a good person. Name: Dee Fee, MD came here    
Name: Kas Egre, MD is a good person. Name: Kas Egre, MD came here
```

This is my code:

```
rename = re.compile(r"""([A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z\s]*[A-Z][a-z]+)(,\s)(MD)""")
match = rename.search(st)
for match in rename.finditer(st):
    if match.group(3) == 'MD':
        new = rename.sub("Name: %s"%(match.group(0)),st)
        print new
```

how can I fix my code? Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `re.sub` with capturing group:

```
>>> import re
>>> st = "Dee Fee, MD is a good person. Kas Egre, MD came here"
>>> rename = re.compile(r'([A-Z][a-z]+\s+[A-Z][a-z]+),\s*\bMD\b')
>>> rename.sub(r'Name: \1', st)
'Name: Dee Fee is a good person. Name: Kas Egre came here'
```

`\1` in the replacement string is replaced with the first captured group (name part).

Comment: Thank you! your code is pretty clean and much easier than mine, and it works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your regex a bit...

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\w+\s+\w+),\s*MD', lambda x: 'Name: '+ x.group(1), st)
'Name: Dee Fee is a good person. Name: Kas Egre came here'
```

Actually, we don't even need a function here since we can insert groups with `\N` (where N is the group number)...

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\w+\s+\w+),\s*MD', r'Name: \1', st)
'Name: Dee Fee is a good person. Name: Kas Egre came here'
```